# python разные значения переменной х в функции и вне

Tags: python, telebot

ожидается что после вывода "правильно" у переменной x вне функции будет значение 1

```
x=0#Правильные ответы
y=0#Неправильные ответы
if x == 0:
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def send_text(message):
    global x
    global y
    if x == 0:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1)правильно   2)неправильно')
      if message.text=='1':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'правильно')
        x += 1
      elif message.text=='2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неправильно')
        y += 1
      elif message.text!='1' or '2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите 1 или 2')

if x == 1:
  print (x)
```

Comment: Нет смысла помещать функцию в if. При выполнении условия if эта функция не выполнится, а выполнится только при приходе сообщения боту. Весь код снаружи функции выполнится сразу при старте программы, а функция выполнится только при приходе сообщения боту, поэтому нет смысла проверять снаружи функции значение.

Comment: Вообще да. `if x == 1:` выполнится заведомо раньше, чем вызовется обработчик бота, который меняет `x`. Нет смысла в такой конструкции.